# A doubt on linear maps from a vector space to its field set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the meaning of the statement : "A vector space $V$ over $F$ can be understood better by looking the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $F$".

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, $\dim_F \mathcal{L}\left(V,F\right)=\left( \dim_F V \right)\times \left(\dim_F F\right)=\dim_F V$ so $\mathcal{L}\left(V,F\right)\cong V$. $\mathcal{L}\left(V,F\right)$ is called the dual space of $V$. But I have no idea why it would be easier to visualize...

Comment: Here is a project for you, Prasenjit: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space and then come back here and summarize what you have learned about what you can understand about a vector space by studying its dual space.